# JQuery : Restricted Duplicate value in jagged array

Tags: jquery

I have this type of jagged array when 
4th position is same (1) then its return true.

```
[
["1","Normal","0.00","1"],
["2","High","0.00","1"],
["3","Medium","0.00","1"],
["4","Low","0.00","1"]
]
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If duplicate record find in 4th postion then its return true.

Comment: Do you need to check the array is having duplicate records.

Comment: no if duplicate record then return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do use this:

```
var inputArray = [
    ["1","Normal","0.01","1"],
    ["2","High","0.03","9"],
    ["3","Medium","0.00","3"],
    ["4","Low","0.00","1"]
];

var hasDuplicate = !!inputArray.find(function(item, index, arr) {
    return !!arr.find(function(itemInner, indexInner, arrInner) {
        return itemInner[2] == item[2] && index != indexInner;
    });
});
alert(hasDuplicate);
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7noyLbe/

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [["1","Normal","0.00","1"],
["2","High","0.00","1"],
["3","Medium","0.00","1"],
["3","Medium","0.00","1"]];

function checkForDuplicate(arr, pos) {
    var itemsToCheck = {};
    var stringifiedPosObj = JSON.stringify(arr[pos]);
    itemsToCheck[stringifiedPosObj] = true;
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(i !== pos) {
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
        if(itemsToCheck[stringified]) { return true; break; }
      }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(checkForDuplicate(arr, 3));
```

The above code will check for duplicates in the given poition

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputArray = [
["1","Normal","0.00","1"],
["2","High","0.00","9"],
["3","Medium","0.00","3"],
["4","Low","0.00","1"]
];
var duplicate = false;
jQuery.each(inputArray, function(index, item){
    if(item.length > 3 && jQuery.grep(inputArray, function(n, i){return n.length > 3 && n[3] == item[3]}).length > 1)
    {
        duplicate = true;
        return false;
    }});
return duplicate;
```

BTW, I edited your input array.